# AI algorithm blind test - sample size

Tags: sample, small-sample, artificial-intelligence

My company works in healthcare consulting, and are working with medical practitioners to explore how AI might be able to assist the remote, early diagnosis of central nervous system disorders such as schizophrenia or Alzheimer's through text-input chatbot or telephone interviews. We have provided a data set of actual diagnosed patient responses (and healthy subject control responses) to a base list of questions for one specific condition. This list reflects best current in-person medical practice interview methodology. Our AI vendor analyzed those responses and built an algorithm which they now claim is "90% accurate" in diagnosing that specific condition with a simple binary yes/no.

We are neither AI experts nor statisticians, and the vendor will not share much of their "secret sauce" to explain the algorithm and what it has determined is important in analyzing these text responses. So we want to do a simple blind test to check their assertion.

My question is about sample size. How many subjects from each of the diagnosed patient and healthy groups do we need to confirm our vendor's actual accuracy? We will need to secure another set of interview responses, which will cost money so would like to know a "minimum" (perhaps 95% accuracy with a plus/minus 3 point margin of error is enough?) and "ideal" number (99% accuracy, same margin of error?) for this test. If you could show the calculation logic as well it would be most helpful!

Comment: Can you describe the data that you gave them? How many units in the sample? Was the data balanced? That is, what was the proportion of yes/no's in the data? Did they say how they obtained that estimate, by which protocol?

Comment: Thanks for the question. We provided them with data for 30 patients and 11 healthy subjects. They told us that they analyzed this along 300 vectors and came up with the most relevant. They have a patented text analysis system focused on a different domain where they are very successful, and say they can't explain much more without giving away secrets. Does this help you?